# Optional Dependencies, Spring and JSR330

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

According to the JSR330 discussions, they rejected the `@Optional` annotation because the equivalent could be done with the `javax.inject.Provider` interface. What I have not managed to do, or find any example of, is how to implement a Provider as JSR330 would expect within Spring. If I do not add a bean e.g. `MyBean` that satisfies the `Provider<MyBean>.get()` it throws an exception. I am aware I can use the `@Autowire` annotation, but I was wondering can anyone demonstrate an implementation that actually works, justifying the JSR330 original objection to `@Optional`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement my own `Provider` class, not that of JSR330. This then became the mandatory dependency, which actually (much like `Provider` and also `Optional` classes) had a `getObject()` method which provided the object.  Unfortunately, you cannot avoid framework dependencies, so I ended up implementing the interface in my framework dependent classes exploiting the framework attributes to do optional dependencies, for example:

```
public class ThreadServiceProvider implements OptionalDependency<ScheduledExecutorService> {

    /** Spring executor factory bean. */
    private ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean provider = null;

    @Override
    public final ScheduledExecutorService getObject() {
        if (provider != null) {
            return provider.getObject();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Sets the factory bean for providing threads.
     * 
     * @param factory
     *            Spring thread factory bean.
     */
    @Autowired(required = false)
    public final void setProvider(final ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean factory) {
        provider = factory;
    }
}
```